# Find the closures of a set of attributes given a relation and FDs

Tags: relation, functional-dependencies, data-management

I've the following relation:

```
R = BCDEFGHI
```

and the following FDs

```
C -> D
E -> D
EF -> G
EG -> F
FG -> E
FH -> C
H -> B
```

I'm asked to find the closure of the following set of attributes:

1. `BC`
2. `BDEFG`
3. `CEFG`
4. `EFG`
5. `EFGH`

### My attempts

1. Let `BC+ = BC`.

   - Using FD `C -> D`, we have `DC+ = BCD`, and we're done.
2. Let `BDEFG+ = BDEFG`.

   - We're done.
3. Let `CEFG+ = CEFG`.

   - Using FD `C -> D`, then `CEFG+ = CEFGD`, and we're done.
4. Let `EFG+ = EFG`.

   - Using FD `E -> D`, then `EFG+ = EFGD`, and we're done.
5. Let `EFGH+ = EFGH`.

   - Using FD `E -> D`, then `EFGH+ = EFGHD`.
   - Using FD `FH -> C`, then `EFGH+ = EFGHDC`
   - Using FD `H -> B`, then `EFGH+ = EFGHDCB`, and we're done.

Since I'm very new to these topics, I'm not sure if what I've done is correct or not. I would appreciate some feedback from you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok. (Assuming that you properly did the steps that you didn't mention, ie decisions re dealing with FDs that you didn't mention and re stopping.)

(Don't say that a closure is equal to something when it isn't. Use some name for the algorithm's accumulator like "1. Let F = BC. Using ... then let F = BCE; Done so BC+ = F = BCE". Or write something like "1. Finding BC+: Using ... then BC+ >= BCE; Done so BC+ = BCE".)